# How does string age affect intonation?

Tags: guitar, tuning, strings, intonation

I had a recent issue with my high e string where the saddle was adjusted as short as possible but the twelfth fret was still very flat. I read online that a new set of strings may fix this, and that turned out to be a perfect solution. My question now is, from a physical standpoint, *why does string age affect intonation?* I can understand why old strings won't hold their tuning as long, but I don't understand how age can throw a strings intonation off.

Comment: What was the string made of?

Comment: Nickel I reckon. The strings were on the guitar when I bought it. Standard electric guitar strings.

Comment: This is just a suspicion, so I won't put it as an answer yet:  As strings age, they stretch.  As they stretch, they become thinner.  Note that the lighter gauge strings have the saddle set shorter than the heavier gauge strings of the same type, though some of that has to do with the height of the action.

Comment: I would claim age in itself does not cause any intonation change. Crud buildup from grubby or sweaty hands does. There's also the bizarre, yet as far I I'm aware untested pseudo-science that one person can kill strings in days while another can keep playing them forever without them going "bad". I used to know a guy who, if you lent him your guitar for an afternoon, within days the strings would need changing. I've known lesser versions of this across many players. Some of my guitars have 15-year-old strings & no intonation or tuning issues [I like mellow on some ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin Good point; aside from chemical corrosion, I wouldn't expect strings *that don't get played on* to go false just from age alone. But if it's true that the problem is from actual mechanical damage or deformity, then it makes sense that more "vigorous" technique might make them die sooner (though I don't know about "in an afternoon"!)

Comment: I'd go so far as to say [with no real citation] that any change in density - adding crud or wearing away on frets - is going to create the issue [though possibly in opposite directions]

Comment: For context the strings were at least a year old, as they were on the guitar when purchased.

Comment: 1) A year is an awfully long time to stick with the same set of strings (it seems to me like guitarists who play regularly love to change strings every week or two; you're lucky they're so affordable compared to bowed-strings strings!). 2) If they were on the instrument when you bought it, and it was out in a music shop, you don't know how much use they got before you bought it. I'd say it's a miracle they lasted a year! (Though all this with the same disclaimer that it's not really *time* in the abstract, but how much use they get.)

Comment: @AndyBonner - just to play devil's advocate. On my Rikki bass when I used to play it all the time, I'd change strings every couple of weeks to keep the 'twang' in. My Strats, however, I don't like the sound until the strings have had at least a month to stop being so damn bright.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've been curious about this too. I imagine this is the same phenomenon that violinists refer to as a string "going false." The effect is the location of pitches becomes inconsistent along the length of the string, especially noticeable on a fretless instrument; i.e. if you tried to play, on two strings, a pitch a perfect fourth higher than the open string, the placement would have to be slightly different on the two strings (which is of course impossible with frets). I've also noticed, especially with an unwound wire string like the violin's high E, that plucking a false string can produce "two pitches," as if an E and another slightly detuned E were being played at the same time.

[This page](https://robertcauerviolins.com/pages/false-strings) simply says "A 'false' string is one with uneven thickness and mass along its length." It suggests that it involves the "flattening" of the round cross-section of the string. [This discussion thread](https://ask.metafilter.com/207712/What-causes-strings-to-go-false) is rambly and largely speculative, but I imagine much of that speculation is true, that it also involves changes to the elasticity of the metal. The fact is, for a wound string, there are so many parts that there could be a lot of factors. The string's core is perhaps a number of braided steel wires, which could become inconsistent in thickness, shape, or elasticity, and the winding could become deformed or perhaps have its "coils" spread apart or together.

Of course, if the new strings *hadn't* solved the problems, there could be other suspects as well. The wood of fretboards wears grooves between the frets over time, and [frets themselves could become worn](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/114440/are-these-indentations-on-the-frets-of-my-acoustic-for-intonation-can-i-apply-t) and be inconsistent from one string to another.

---

> I can understand why old strings won't hold their tuning as long...

Actually, I would expect (and find, in practice) the opposite. New strings always have a "break-in period" during which they stretch and have to be retuned regularly (the period varies in length and intensity depending on the material), but once they've "settled in," they generally hold their pitch quite well (unless maybe eventually some mechanical flaw like we've been discussing impacts their stability).

Answer (score 10):

tl,dr: Finger gunk.

It's the same reason why strings become dull over time. When playing. the oil, sweat and salt from your fingers interacts with the string and results in corrosion and accumulation.

This is more pronounced where you fret the most and this results in an uneven mass distribution and the center of gravity moves slightly away from the 12th fret. Hence it's out of intonation.

Comment: If you observe the 12th fret tone to be flat compared to the 0th flat, then the finger gunk theory would mean that more finger gunk accumulates in the upper half of the string than in the lower half.  As the left hand contributes more finger gunk than the right hand does, this would suggest that a lot of the playing was happening above the octave (which would strike me as unusual playing style).  So the outcome, a flat octave, would be a slightly unexpected consequence of finger gunk accumulation.

Comment: The finger gunk theory is testable.  Soak your strings in ethanol for 24 hours and see what happens with finger gunk gone.

Comment: @JirkaHanika, I suspect the physics is much more complex. Presumably, the effect of finger gunk is to cause differentials in dampening and tension across the length of a single string. Those effects probably interact with string use, such that higher use + finger gunk impacts the string differently than lower use + finger gunk. Another element to consider is the cumulative effect of many spots where the strings are degraded. I feel like the math would need to be worked out to show that this would *always* produce flatness in every instance. Soaking in ethanol won't reverse permanent damage.

Comment: @jdjazz - That's the point.  Cleaning the string lets you separate wear effects from gunk effects.  What will be the finding?  I don't know.  I do get your point about dampening versus weight.  Perhaps not about tension though, tension has to be constant even on an unevenly gunky string.

Comment: @JirkaHanika maybe I'm not familiar enough with the gunk theory. I thought it was proposing a mechanism that causes the wear on the strings. The physics is starting to go beyond my knowledge, but I thought the tension isn't constant (1) if the string has kinks, (2) if there's an applied force on the string (not really relevant in this scenario), (3) or if the string is accelerating different masses along the length. Without a ton of direct knowledge, I'd guess that the 3rd is most relevant here, since each bit of string is accelerating as it vibrates, and those bits can have different masses.

Comment: @JirkaHanika, in other words, I thought the final instance of differential tension along the string would arise when a string of non-constant density/ mass is accelerating (eg vibrating and producing sound).

Comment: @jdjazz - Our fingers are covered with keratin, oiled with sebum.  As new skin and nails grow, this substance (keratin dust soaked in sebum) sticks to what we touch.  A good place to look for the substance is under one's nails or along very old, never cleaned strings.  One potential effect of this is that the dirty part of the string could become heavier than the cleaner part.  Another effect could perhaps be some kind of a dampening effect, although I don't subscribe to that.  Tension isn't affected by kinks or material or even by the weight.  Ethanol dissolves sebum a keratin dust drops out.

Comment: @JirkaHanika, thanks for the background on finger gunk! I wonder if you're thinking only of massless strings? If a string has mass, simply hanging it vertically will produce more tension at the top than the bottom of the string. If there are differences in linear mass density along the length, then different parts of the string will undergo different accelerations when the same force is applied. To me, it seems like this would impact the vibrational frequencies in complex ways. See, for ex, [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/156417) & [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/460519).

Comment: @jdjazz - The physics of a vibrating string is indeed more complicated.  You can look at a vibrating horizontal guitar string to see the proportions of the forces: the vertical [restoring force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restoring_force) is way bigger than the gravitational deformation (as the midpoint goes about as high above the horizontal as below it), but also much smaller than the horizontal tension.  And of course I'm talking about massive strings with potentially massive gunk.  A massless string has an infinitely high pitch and so it can't be heard.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the already given answers are also right, in the sense that the mentioned factor physically modify the harmonic response of the string.
But I think soaking in ethanol for 24 hours will not make the string new, because of a physical phenomenon called "fatigue", that I guess plays the main role here.

As you know every material have his own elastic constant E (young modulus), in the case of steel it is around E=210 GPa.
The fatigue is a phenomenon that ""make the material weaker"" when the same point of material is subjected repeatedly to many cycles of the same load.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatigue_(material)
You can see that e.g. the "main" LA string goes 440 Hz (around? sorry i'm just half musician), so it does 880 cycles from minimum tension to max every second that it vibrate.
Every material have its own characteristic number of allowed cycles before suffering of fatigue (see Whaler function). From this number you can compute by simple division the number of seconds that the string can vibrate before suffering of fatigue.
This phenomenon modify the value of this Young coefficient E (and also others like Poisson coeff., more complicated, just doesn't matter, but the idea is the same).
But as you know the vibrating string doesn't have the same tension everywhere:
every harmonic have his own wavelength. Assuming the string is vibrating sinusoidally, in a full period we have one max and one min points (the one with horizontal tangent line, i.e. derivative 0, for those who knows a bit of math)
and those points will be the most strained ones. Instead, the nodes of the mode will be less strained ( this because the differential equation of the vibrating string is
Yxx=k*Ytt where k basically is modified by tuning. xx and tt are partial derivations). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_mode
To conclude, the string will fatigue not in a constant way, but differently in every point. If you add this to all imperfections (like that touching the string non uniformly will consume it non uniformly for example), after a while the string doesn't perform as new.